# Buck Converter MOSFET Output Voltage distorted (PWM)

Tags: mosfet, pwm, power-electronics, buck, duty-cycle

The input to my buck converter MOSFET switch is a PWM signal with a certain duty cycle. However, upon observing the voltage waveform of the MOSFET, the voltage is a bit distorted.

The input to MOSFET (PWM signal) and output of MOSFET is observed and pictures are attached.

The first picture is **PWM Input to MOSFET (Blue Waveform)** and the 2nd picture is **MOSFET Output Voltage (Blue Waveform)**

Thanks

[image: **PWM Input to MOSFET**]

[image: **MOSFET Output Voltage**]

Comment: This is normal and everything is fine. Simply your inductor work in DCM mode, that's all.

Comment: Actually, I am new to power electronics and I have to write an answer for this question, as to carry out a comparison. 

So would  "The inductor is working in DCM mode" suffice?

Comment: Try read this http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/ssqu007b/ssqu007b.pdf page 36

Comment: This application report concentrates directly on CCM/DCM operation: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva057/slva057.pdf

Comment: Thank you. The readings helped alot